# Changing URL in Wordpress : Absolute links

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm currently changing the URL of a Wordpress website, and I've got problems with it...
First of all, let's write versions of what I'm using

- Wordpress: 4.5.3
- MySQL: 5.5
- PHP: 5.6

The website is hosted at `www.xxx.com/blog/`and when I access this URL, everything is working as expected, but I want to change this URL to `www.yyy.com/`

So I paid a domain name `www.yyy.com/`(with http://godaddy.com) and I made a **forward with masking** from `yyy.com`to`xxx.com/blog`

So now, when I access `www.yyy.com/`, I access the home page of the website, and the URL is `www.yyy.com` but here start to be the problem...

Only the home page is working, all the links to the posts are dead... 
So I made a search and replace in the database, and I change all the link `www.xxx.com/blog/2016/zzz` to `www.yyy.com/2016/zzz` and when I access them directly by URL it's working, but when I access them by clicking on the website, the link is `www.xxx.com/blog/2016/zzz` and the URL is staying `www.yyy.com` (not keeping trace of `/2016/zzz`...)

So I then find out that there are 2 variables in the database:

- `siteurl` = `www.xxx.com/blog/`
- `home`    = `www.xxx.com/blog/`

and if I change just one of these 2 variables to `www.yyy.com/` the website dies, I get a blank page and nothing is not working anymore...

So currently, I've got:

- A domain name `yyy.com` which make a forward with masking to `xxx.com/blog/`
- All the link the posts are `www.yyy.com/2016/zzz` in the database.
- Access the URL `www.yyy.com/2016/zzz` directly is working.
- Access the URL `www.yyy.com/` directly is working.
- `siteurl` = `www.xxx.com/blog/`
- `home`    = `www.xxx.com/blog/`

Problems that need to be fixed:

- Links on the website are still `www.xxx.com/blog/2016/zzz`
- `siteurl` and `home` are the old URL but if I change them, I've got a blank page.

I hope anyone had already this issue and will be able to help me :)

---

**EDIT**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file change the rewritebase to `/` instead of `/blog/` when you are using www.yyy.com, then change siteurl and home to www.yyy.com

Comment: Please post your current .htaccess settings here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer, I just tried it and it still not working :/

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail Did you change change siteurl and home to www.yyy.com? If yes, the do this : search and replaced all the `xxx.com/blog` with `yyy.com`

Comment: I did what you proposed, and now I've got a 404 on the home page. I don't really know what's going on right now. There is no more trace of "xxx.com/blog" but yyy.com is a 404 ...